# why does "echo "qwerty" | /bin/sh" return "/bin/sh: 1: qwerty: not found"?

Tags: shell, sh, echo

I know that `echo` command displays the line of text that is passed as argument.

So the syntax `echo "qwerty"` would display:

> qwerty

but when I merge the previous syntax with `| /bin/sh` the following message is displayed:

> /bin/sh: 1: qwerty: not found

I would like to know why using bitwise OR operator (i.e. `|` ) this way ending up with such an output.

Comment: In a shell `|` is a pipe, not bitwise or. What does this have to do with C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is not a bitwise OR operator.<sup>[1]</sup> It's a pipe operator. It causes the stdout of the preceding program to be piped to the stdin of the following program.

```
$ printf 'abc def\nghi\n' | wc
      2       3       12
```

This shows `wc` ("word count") reading the output of `printf` and printing out the fact that it received 2 lines, 3 words and 12 bytes.

In your case, `sh` reads its stdin for commands (due to the absence of both a `-c` option and a file name argument), and thus treats `qwerty` as a command to execute.

---

1. It can be bitwise OR in arithmetic context when using `bash` and possibly other shells in the "sh family". That's not the case here even if you were using `bash`.